# Como pasar objeto a funcion javascript en onclick event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

desde una lista de objetos, recorrer con each, y por cada fila pasar el objecto completo a una funcion javascript, en donde pueda tener acceso a los datos y eventualmente convertir dicho objeto a json. En mis intentos solo obtengo [object].

La idea es pasar el objeto completo en una funcion javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("ListOfCars")",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    dataType: "JSON",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        if ($.trim(data)) {
            $(data).each(function () {
                $("#car_rows").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + this.ID + "</td>" +
                "<td><a href="#" onclick="functionTest(\'' + data + '\');">Ver Detalle</a>' +</td>" +
                '</td>'+ "</tr>"
            }
        }
    }
})
functionTest(obj) {
    var test = JSON.stringify(obj);
}
```

En la variable test no puedo acceder a ningun dato. Alguna solución?

Ejemplo Json:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "777846730",
    "OrderDate": "2018-08-27T00:00:00",
    "AccountClient": "55474",
    "DaysToClaim": 1,
    "Courier": {
      "ID": "BEX",
      "Name": "Express",
      "Active": false
    },
    "CustomerOrder": {
      "OrderNbr": "78577",
      "DocumentNbr": "1117",
      "Date": "2018-08-26T00:00:00",
      "PaymentType": "MC",
      "TotalAmount": "14444"
    },
    "DeliveryAddress": {
      "Address": "CAMINO A BUENA PAZ~6",
      "Number": null,
      "References": ""
    },
    "Customer": {
      "ID": "524",
      "DocumentNbr": "",
      "Name": "JOSE AGUSTIN PARDO ORELLANA",
      "Phone": "979797"
    },
    "ClaimDetail": {
      "DateClaim": "2018-09-06T15:28:07",
      "Observation": "test 1",
      "User": "user1"
    },
    "LastDeliveryStatus": {
      "ID": "OK",
      "Name": "OK",
      "Date": "2018-09-13T13:21:37",
      "Description": "test 1",
      "GlobalStatus": {
        "ID": null,
        "Name": null,
        "IsActive": false,
        "TotalOrder": 0,
        "Icon": null,
        "Color": null,
        "Orders": []
      },
      "Detail": {
        "PostalNbr": null,
        "PostalName": "Matriz"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

El cual se esta retornando con la siguiente linea:

```
return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: ¿ Puedes mostrar el json que recibes?

Comment: @mariovzc ese es el json que estoy pasando :)

Comment: Pregunta para que pasarias todos los objetos despues de hacer un foreach?? Y para que necesitas toda la data fuera de que cada click haria exactamente lo mismo? No es mejor almacenar la data en una variable y cuando se de click solo usar dicha variable...

Answer (score 1):

Aqui te dejo una manera de hacerlo, el código se puede simplificar mucho gracias a jQuery, pero en mi opinión queda "guarro". Asi que lo dejo escrito de una manera más legible para que puedas ver los pasos:

```
success: function (data) {
    data.forEach(d => {

    // Creamos los elementos

    const linea = $('<tr></tr>');

    const col1 = $('<td></td>');

    const col2 = $('<td></td>');

    const link = $('<a></a>');

    col1.html(d.ID);

    link.html('Ver Detalle').attr('href', 'javascript: void(0)').on('click', functionTest);

    link[0].obj = d; // Guardamos el objeto en una variable dentro del nodo nativo

    col2.append(link);

    linea.append(col1).append(col2);

    $("#car_rows").append(linea);

  })
}
```

Y la función:

```
function functionTest(e) {

    var test = e.currentTarget.obj;

    console.log(test)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que tienes un error de sintaxis en la concatenación de tu variable data.

```
"<td><a href='#' onclick='functionTest('" + data + "');'>Ver Detalle</a></td>"
```

Prueba con algo como esto, y me cuentas como te va.

Comment: Probé tu observación pero tengo el siguiente error: getStatusChange(

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Mas que sintaxis, me parece que es algo faltante en el código. Porque logro pasar el objeto pero lo visualizo así: "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] ...